# How to assign variable from inside an if expression?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to assign value to a variable inside the if expression.

```
func message() -> Int?{
  var y = "" 
  if x.Sender(msg, reply: { message in
      replyFunc {
          if message.command == .success {
               y = "Hello World"
               print(y) //It prints hello world
          }   
       }   
  }) {   
      print("Error") 
  }
  return y //Here I don't get Hello World
}
```

I want to assign 'y' from inside the expression.

Edit: This issue is of asynchronous callback and please refer to Matt's comment for the tutorial.

Comment: And what prevents you from doing so? Is there a compile error?

Comment: I don't get the output for y as hello world

Comment: You won't get the output.  Because your print executes before closure executes

Comment: But I know that the variable is set to Hello World. But the string becomes empty when I print it at the end.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the "print" statement and set a breakpoint at the setting statement.  The print will hit before the set will

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using playground so I can't set breakpoint.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `if` expressions, and everything with asynchronous processing.

Comment: So, what can I do about it? Is there anyway to delay it or make it execute at the end?

Comment: Simply do the printing inside the closure, when the value has been set.

Comment: What you need to do is break out the handling of the return of message() and have the closure call THAT when it gets executed

Comment: Can you please give me a syntax for that?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: The code doesn't even compile. You cannot **`return`** something from an asynchronous completion handler because it doesn't have a return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question a lot of new to swift/async programmers fall.

Either `Sender` or `ReplyFunc` are async functions: Meaning they will open a new thread(for simplicity sake) and do the assignment there. Two things will happen in parallel and you cant know which going to be first. Because Entering closure and then entering another closure is more work in reality order of execution might be:

- First: `return y`
- Second: `y = "whatever string you had to assign"`

**Solution**:
Return completion closure.

```
    func message(completion: (String)->()) {
        if x.Sender(msg, reply: { message in
            replyFunc {
                if message.command == .success {
                    completion("Hello World")//It send hello world
                } else {
                    completion("Failure")
                }
            }
        }) {
            completion("Error")
        }
    }
```

Consuming Y:

```
    message { y in
        print(y) // here is my "Hello World" or "Error" when error
    }
```

**NOTE:** 
You must always, with all flows, run completion, this is a best practice.

Answer (score -3):

```
func someMethod() {
    _ = message()
}

func handleReply(message: SomeType) {
    if message.command = .success {
        y = "Hello World"
    }
}

func message() -> Int?{
      var y = "" 
      if x.Sender(msg, reply: { message in
          replyFunc {
              handleReply(message)
           }   
      }) {   
          print("Error") 
      }
      return y //Here I don't get Hello World
    }
```

Comment: I have edited the code. I am not getting the output for y as Hello World. Instead I get an empty string.

Comment: See my comment above.  The print() executes before the closure does.

Comment: Okay, so you mean the print statement at the end executes before the if expression?

Comment: Correct.  The 'if' statement is inside a closure